# msal/angular reloads page mulitple times

Tags: azure-ad-msal, msal-angular

I'm facing an issue where MSAL is reloading the page multiple times trying to get an authentication token. I'm using the below `APP_INITIALIZER` to handle the authentication. When I clear all the tokens out and start at a fresh page load, I get this sequence in the output.

1. Navigated to http://localhost:4200/myPage

   - Console shows: initialize, handleRedirectPromise, getAllAccounts
2. Navigated to the login.microsoftonline.com page
3. Navigated to http://localhost:4200

   - Console shows: initialize, handleRedirectPromise
4. Navigated to http://localhost:4200/myPage

   - Console shows: initialize, handleRedirectPromise
   - Console then shows two acquireTokenSilent rejected with error messages
   - Console then shows setActiveAccount, initialize, handleRedirectPromise
5. Navigated to http://localhost:4200

   - I assume the initialize/handleRedirectPromise previous are from this and just out of order.
6. Navigated to http://localhost:4200/myPage

   - Console shows: initialize, handleRedirectPromise, setActiveAccount

Why are steps three, four and five happening?

```js
export const provideAzure = () => makeEnvironmentProviders([
    {
        provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
        useFactory: (msalService: MsalService, msalBroadcastService: MsalBroadcastService) => async () => {
            console.info('initialize')
            await publicClientApplication.initialize()

            console.info('handleRedirectPromise')
            const redirect = await msalService.instance.handleRedirectPromise()

            if (redirect?.account) {
                console.info('setActiveAccount')
                msalService.instance.setActiveAccount(redirect.account)
            } else {
                console.info('getAllAccounts')
                const accounts = msalService.instance.getAllAccounts()

                if (accounts.length > 0) {
                    console.info('setActiveAccount')
                    msalService.instance.setActiveAccount(accounts[0])
                }
            }
        },
        multi: true,
        deps: [MsalService, MsalBroadcastService]
    },
    {provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: MsalInterceptor, multi: true},
    MsalService,
    MsalGuard
])
```

I'm using @azure/msal-angular 3.0.4 and @azure/msal-browser 3.10.0 with Angular 16.1.2

Comment: Can you provide a minimal repro? unnecessary reloads kinda sound like a missing iframe check in the app.component.ts but this is not much info to go on.